# How to auto-generate a random number from a primary key column after inserting a data in the table by using SQL query only?

Tags: sql-server

What I am trying to achieve is that when a student data gets entered in a `Student` table, a randomly auto-generated ID number should be generated from the primary key column.

Every time new student data is entered, the randomly auto-generated ID number should have the following criteria:

1. It should always start with the character 'CTI'
2. A random 7-digit number should be generated after 'CTI'.

Something like this: `CTI2021391`

This is what I have tried:

```
CREATE DATABASE Student_Registration

CREATE TABLE Student
(
    ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Student_No AS RIGHT ('CTI' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)), 10) PERSISTED PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Student_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Student (Student_Name) VALUES ('Larry Mullen')
INSERT INTO Student (Student_Name) VALUES ('Paul Hewson')
INSERT INTO Student (Student_Name) VALUES ('Adam Clayton')
INSERT INTO Student (Student_Name) VALUES ('David Evans')

SELECT * 
FROM Student
```

The problem is that the primary key column is displaying the following output:

```
ID  Student_No   Student_Name
------------------------------
1   CTI1         Larry Mullen
2   CTI2         Paul Hewson
3   CTI3         Adam Clayton
4   CTI4         David Evans
```

But what I am trying to achieve is that the primary key column should auto-generate any random 7-digit number after 'CTI' character.

Something like this:

```
Student_No  Student_Name
--------------------------
CTI2021391  Larry Mullen
CTI2985748  Paul Hewson
CTI9872573  Adam Clayton
CTI7203158  David Evans
```

I am trying to achieve the above desired result by relying on `Student_No` primary key column.

And I don't want to rely on `ID INTEGER(1,1)` at all.

How can this issue be solved ?

Any recommended solution to this issue will be highly appreciated

Comment: Careful with requirements like this, you could easily result with clashes and they are completely out of your control. You might well be better off pre-generating the numbers and then when you `INSERT` a new row you get the next value from the pre-generated values, while locking the table (of pre-generated values) and marking it as used.

Comment: Yes! Please generate the numbers up front. If you try to generate them as you go, your chances for collisions (and, more importantly, the cost of checking for them) goes up exponentially. See [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3055/generating-random-numbers-in-sql-server-without-collisions/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) for the approach I use, which maintains a stable execution time throughout all number "generations" throughout the range, and avoids collisions entirely.

Comment: _A random 7-digit number_ What if the randomly generated "number" is 1? "1" is just as random as "2021391". Or is your requirement a random number between 1000000 and 9999999? Or perhaps you just zero pad a random number that is less than 7 characters in length? Writing good requirements is difficult!

Comment: @SMor ... My requirement is any 7-digit random number from 0000000 to 9999999.
The randomly auto-generated 7 digit random number will be concatenated with the string 'CTI' to show something like CTI1612894.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why you need this? It may be that your need is better solved some other way.

Comment: @majjam .... For example, when a student gets registered in a University, they receive their unique ID number something like  'TPM3270154' OR 'CTI2021391' OR  'JCU4509128'.
From my understanding, to achieve these randomly generated numbers can be achieved through programming. But, I am trying to solve this just by relying on SQL.
I was wondering do I need create any Stored Procedure or Function or SEQUENCE for this ?

Comment: I doubt that you can use a non-deterministic function that generates a random value for a computed column.  And there's the concern of collision with an existing generated id. But maybe something less random like `CONCAT('CTI',RIGHT(CONCAT(CHECKSUM(Student_Name,ID),ID),7))`. Eventually it'll collide, but it'll take a while.

Comment: @LukStorms I suppose you could just put a unique index on the Student_No column, that would ensure there are never any duplicates

Comment: I was thinking you could just append the padded ID so ID = 1, Student_No = CTI0000001 etc, would that work? Is it important they are random / random-looking?

Comment: @majjam The OP made Student_No the Primary Key, so there can't be dups. But the point is that an insert would fail if it generates a dup.